# `gem install tiny_tds` on OS X Yosemite failing with "You have to install development tools first."

Tags: ruby, macos, gcc, osx-yosemite

Looking for a wise sage to point me in the right direction for what I can do next.

I use RVM and brew on OS X. I've confirmed that xcode is up to date and that xcode command line tools are installed.

I'm hitting this error during `gem install tiny_tds`

> /Users/bdx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in
>   'try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file.
>   (RuntimeError)
>
> You have to install development tools first.
>   from /Users/bdx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:461:in 'try_link0'
>   from /Users/bdx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:476:in 'try_link'
>   from /Users/bdx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:619:in 'try_func'

I added some debug logging to `mkmf.rb` to see what was going on at that point.

The call to `try_do` was passing the following in the `command` argument:

**command**

```
/usr/local/opt/gcc46/bin/gcc-4.6 -o conftest -I/Users/bdx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin13.4.0 -I/Users/bdx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/Users/bdx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -I/Users/bdx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/mysql/include -I/opt/X11/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include  -O3 -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration  -fno-common -pipe  conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/bdx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib -L/Users/bdx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/mysql/lib -L/opt/X11/lib -L/usr/local/git/lib -L/Users/bdx/.rvm/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L. -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib       -lruby.1.9.1  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc
```

Following that `command` argument, I found that `/usr/local/opt/gcc46/bin/gcc-4.6` didn't exist. Doing `locate gcc-4.6` found its path for me, so I ran: `ln -s /usr/local/opt/gcc46/bin/gcc-4.6 /usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/gcc-4.6` and tried again, but the same error keeps occurring.

Comment: Just for kicks I would try updating your Ruby if you are still on 1.9.3 to see if that works.

Comment: Turns out that was it... I was avoiding doing that upgrade because of other gems I had that relied on it, I'll now find replacements for those.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same error -

> You have to install development tools first

when tried to install tiny_tds gem. When inspecting the log file mkmf.rb, I found the error was:

> xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun

Running `xcode-select --reset` fixed the problem for me.